# Communication, Wording, Elaboration, Language Expression

Tags: pre-schooler, development, education, language-development, bilingual

How can a parent that has a severe problem in communication, wording, elaboration and language expession without any problems with the languages in themselves communicate with their offspring so as to teach informally the offspring the skills the parent lacks? I am interested in both Writing and Speaking.

I am verbose, pedantic, inflexible, redundant, and repetitive. I speak, write, or type and what people understand( inference based on the response and any  reasoning they give as to why they responded that way or how they reached their conclusion). I understand they probably have understood something different from what I meant so I blame myself.

I know that one can teach just through their example. I am interested or even minimizing/avoiding the problem.

Nota bene. I tried to break [Functional illiteracy, Reading and Listening](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/functional-illiteracy-reading-and-listening) in two so as to avoid any too broad flags, forgive me if a failed to.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly is the problem you're trying to prevent passing on? Is it verbosity, inflexibility, etc.? Because these are character traits that manifest themselves in your speech, not a speech problem in itself, and the way to avoid passing this down is to eliminate this behavior (which may or may not be emulated by your offspring.)

Comment: Try to communicate primary with nursery rhymes, baby songs and picture books for children.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am a terrible transmitter. Communications(Transmitting) fail so I often blame myself, the transmitter instead of the receptor. I often do not understand how people characterize me( verbose, redundant, inflexible, repetitive) but I choose to accept these characteristics and I try to fix them. People are not very fond of explaining things they think are obvious. I could never get any help( I was trying to understand, learn, and fix my transmitting since primary school). Now I came to accept my problem and I am trying to prevent teaching my transmitting problem to my offspring.

Answer (score 1):

This  very simple: You’re not allowed, you have to forbid yourself to use more than one adjective, more than one verb, more than one noun, more than on subject, more than one object or adverb in one sentence respectively in one phrase especially when you give advices, orders, instructions etc. etc. This will discipline yourself to be short and not long, evasive and long threaded. Try to communicate with 3-5 word phrases.

Edit:

There‘s nothing wrong explaining an instruction. 
Try to mind communicating by *supply and demand*. Give the others a chance for asking. Mind foot ball or tennis:  Pass the ball and wait. Speak like breathing. Speak and wait. Count to ten. Ask: you know what I mean?

Comment: It is easy to give advice, orders, instructions with 3-5 words. But I am compeled to explain Why and if needed How. Do not touch the hob/plug/oven. I feel the imperative need to go on and say because you will get burned/electrocuted. And things just get worse when things are more of house rules or personal opinions. Do not go out. I have a problem explaining in few words why shouldn't the kid go out. The kid often asks/argues and I am always ready to explain with even more details.